# jquery find if its json or xml

Tags: jquery, xml, json, response

i want to know if the response is the json or xml, how can i find that out using jquery?

my current code is following, but its giving error, if response is json.

```
var is_xml = ($('status_code', XMLHttpRequest.responseText)) ? true : false;
```

error is:

> Selector expected.
>
> Expected ',' or '{' but found '"}}"'.

Comment: "'status_code', XMLHttpRequest.responseText" doesn't look like a valid selector

Comment: yes.. cause its reponse is in json, if it was xml, it would be valid selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxError#callback), the third parameter to an `ajaxError` callback is the options object which was passed into the call to `jQuery.ajax`.  You can query the `dataType` value of that object to determine if the call was expected to return json or xml.  Of course, this assumes you set the `dataType` option appropriately to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the return format not consistent? IMO you should know exactly what should come back before even requesting the page.

Comment: because some of the methods are using xml and some json, because of some reason and this was implemented on ajax_error, so ajax error gets trigger if there was any error or a bad response, it will show bad response from xml/json response. :)

any solution please!

Comment: Well then why can't you define *two* functions to do the ajax part, one for json and one for xml?

Comment: why make two methods, when you can get the job done with one. anyway its solved, thank you for getting involve :)

Comment: Well, the answer chosen was pretty much what I was trying to say in that you had to know what you were working with to send the dataType which is before you receive it...

Comment: @meder, I agree with you.  +1